# Specific SQL Binding in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I need a bit of a help.

I have 2 SQL Tables

---

```
CREATE TABLE Education
(
    ID          INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name        NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE DATE
(
    ID          INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    EducationID INT FOREIGN KEY (EducationID) REFERENCES Education(Id) NOT NULL,
    DateTime    NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    CityId      INT FOREIGN KEY (CityId) REFERENCES City(Id) NOT NULL,
    StudNumber  INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    Full        DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
)
```

---

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="myContent" runat="server">
    <br />

<div>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 28%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 44%; text-align:justify"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Italic="true"  Text="Da biste upisali željenu edukaciju, potrebno je iz padajućih izbornika odabrati edukaciju, grad održavanja i termin.
            Zatim popunite potrebne podatke i pritisnite Pošalji predbilježbu. U izbornicima se pokazuju edukacije koje nisu popunjene."></asp:Label></td>
        <td style="width: 28%;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br /><br />
</div>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 20%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblEdukacija" runat="server" Text="Odaberite edukaciju:" Font-Bold="true" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEdukacija" runat="server" DataSourceID="sbsSeminari" DataTextField="Naziv" DataValueField="Id" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList></td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 20%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblGrad" runat="server" Text="Odaberite grad:" Font-Bold="true" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGrad" runat="server" DataTextField="Grad" DataValueField="Id" DataSourceID="sbsGradovi" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:DropDownList></td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 20%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblTermin" runat="server" Text="Odaberite termin:" Font-Bold="true" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTermini" runat="server" DataTextField="Datum" DataValueField="Id" DataSourceID="sbsTermini" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:DropDownList></td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using SeminapAPP.Entities;

namespace SeminapAPP
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

So for every education in first table I have 4 education dates in second table. When a date gets 14 students bit named FULL is activated and that date is Full so nobody can sing up for it.

In my Default.aspx I have to dropdown lists. In first dropdown list I bounded first table, and when I select a education in first dropdown list in second dropdown list i get all dates for that education that are not full.

There is one thing I don't know how to write and I need help. I would like to make that if all 4 dates for education are full, that education is not showed in first dropdown list ? Can it be done ?

So basicly I need a form a query to cahnge in my database source, because I didn't bound my dropdown list in "code behind" but directly in aspx file.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Put your code in the question and explain the problem. It sounds like you need to familiarize yourself with sql.

Comment: My solution is tha I use this query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Date where EducationId=x" and to implement it in my code. If Count is 0 don't show this education in dropdown list if it is >0 then show it. Problem is I don't know how to implement this soultion because i didn't write my code i aspx.cs file, but in my aspx file.

Comment: Update your question by adding your C# and aspx code.

Comment: Question is updated with code.